# Custom Action session.message not showing messagebox

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

I am creating a MSI based Installer using Wix.

My Custom Action declaration goes like this...

```
<Binary Id="CustomActions" SourceFile="DLLs\CustomActions.CA.dll" />

<CustomAction Id="CheckPath" Return="check" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="CustomActions" DllEntry="CheckPath" />
```

And under WixUI_InstallDir Dialog UI,

```
<UI Id="WixUI_InstallDir">
    .....
    <Publish Dialog="SelectDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="CheckPath" Order="2">1</Publish>
    .....
</UI>
```

And in C# file,

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult CheckPath(Session session)
{
      Record record2 = new Record();
      record.FormatString = "The path that you have selected is invalid!";
      session.Message(InstallMessage.Error | (InstallMessage)MessageButtons.OK, record);
      return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

I am expecting a Message box via the above Custom Action when the user selects an invalid path. But the message box is not shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the alternative? I need something similar to work for me

Answer (score 7):

Custom actions triggered via a DoAction control event cannot show message boxes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: What is the alternative? I need something similar to work for me